# Pros and Cons of Cross Site Publishing?

Tags: cross-site-publishing

I'm working on a project in which I want to Catalog enable Libraries in different site collections and surface the content in a Content Search Web Part.  The IT team seem to be offering workflow related alternatives but aren't explaining the push back against Cross Site Publishing.

Are there issues associated with XSP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat anecdotal and opinion based. Others may disagree.

I worked on one largish project a couple years ago that used cross site publishing. I recall it being very difficult to set up and even more difficult to troubleshoot when things go wrong. Sometimes things go wrong and there's little you can do to figure out why.

The feature really only made sense in the context of a public facing web site, where anonymous users don't have access to the underlying content but can browse the published results. For any other use case, there are better ways to deliver functionality. (And I'd argue that with some code we can enable better ways even in a public facing perspective).

I think your IT team has valid reason to steer clear of cross site publishing.

Consider writing a new question with some more detail about your requirements, and why you think XSP might be a good fit, and ask for alternatives.